# Ordering in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've two targets `foo` and `bar`.  Neither depend on the other, but if `bar` has to be rebuilt, it has to be done before `foo`.  They are what gnu-make calls phony targets, their rules have always to be executed when they are specified.

Currently, we express a main target which depends on both like this:

```
# user level targets
all: bar
        @$(MAKE) foo
        @echo all

alt: foo
        @echo alt

# internal targets
foo:
        @echo foo

bar: qux
        @echo bar

qux:
        @echo qux
        @touch qux
```

and we have the required behavior: if qux is not up-to-date: `make bar` outputs `qux bar foo all` (in that order) and `make alt` outputs `foo alt`; if qux is up-to-date, `make bar` output `bar foo all` and `make alt` outputs `foo alt`.

This is increasingly uncomfortable as `foo` has to be handled specifically (all targets which depend on both have to be handled that way, `foo` can't be put in a variable describing dependencies if `bar` is also there, the submake is itself an issue and the command line has to be maintained to pass additional variables). We now have another target which has to be handled in the same way and I'm looking for other, more convenient, ways to handle the structure.

---

Note 1 : In practice, I'm currently using only gnu-make but the only known dependency on a gnu-make extension over POSIX is the possibility to include files (which is quite widely available).  I'd prefer something which keep the current state (i.e. widely supported constructs), but if it is not possible, the use of a gnu-make only extension is acceptable.

---

Note 2: gnu-make has a notion of *order-only-prerequisites*, but it apparently doesn't provide what we need.  With

```
# user level targets
all: bar foo 
        @echo all

alt: foo
        @echo alt

# internal targets
foo: | bar
        @echo foo

bar:
        @echo bar
```

`make alt` also build `bar` (if a file `bar` exist, its date doesn't influence the decision of rebuilding `foo`, which is the documented behavior).

---

Note 3:  The more I think about it, the less I think it is possible to solve this problem with `make` without using a recursive call.  It seems to me that it need two passes on the dependency graph, one to determine what has to be built, one to determine the ordering and I know nothing in `make` behavior which can't be done with a one pass algorithm.

Comment: I'll have to think about this more but the only thing I can think of offhand is to conditionally add that order-only dependency to `foo` when both `foo` and `bar` are specified on the command line (or the default target is in effect).

Comment: @EtanReisner, usually neither is.  It it `all` or `alt` which are specified. (I've expanded to second example to better show that).

Comment: Same idea though (and if you don't care about `make foo`, `make bar` or `make foo bar` working that makes it even easier).

Comment: @Etan, although I can see how to work something from your idea for the command line arguments, for dependencies of those, I'm out of my depth.  I hope what I've omitted from the context won't prevent your idea to work. (I tried without success to add dependencies using target specific variables)

Comment: You can't do this for arbitrary dependencies unfortunately. Those aren't calculated in time. The problem here is really that `foo` *does* depend on `bar` but you are explicitly preventing make from knowing that. Fixing that would be better. Is there no way to tell whether `bar` needs to be re-run that make can be taught about?

Comment: "Neither depend on the other, but if bar has to be rebuilt, it has to be done before foo."  This is a direct contradiction.

Comment: @reinierpost, `foo` does not depend on `bar`: simply building `foo`should not trigger a build of `bar`, even if it is not up-to-date.  Yet there is a relationship between `foo` and `bar` and thus if a make invocation has to build both, `bar` has to be built the first.

Comment: @AProgrammer: So is it fine if `make foo` only rebuilds `foo` without rebuilding `bar`? Does that really always produce a correct `foo`? Or should it error out with a message "sorry, but you really need to rebuild `bar` first"?

Comment: @reinierpost, it's the goal.  You may think to `foo` as `all` and `bar` as `clean` (it's not really the case and I was rather slow to think about the analogy).  I don't want to make clean if I'm doing make all, but if I do both, I want the clean to be completed before starting making all or I'll have issues.

Comment: In that case, you can use a sentinel file `.barred` to indicate that no `bar` operation needs to be done. Make `bar` and `foo` depend on it and give it `bar`'s recipe(s), prepended by  `rm -f $@`.

Comment: @reinierpost, either I've not understood what your propose or it won't work.  bar will not be redone once the sentinel file exists and I don't see how to remove it in time.  And if `qux` is not update, the sentinel file will be redone even if I ask only for `foo`.

Comment: @AProgrammer: it still doesn't make sense to me why you insist on preventing `make foo bar` from first making `foo` (possibly without having remade`bar`) and then remaking `bar` anyway, while `make foo; make bar` would do the exact same thing.

Comment: @reinierpost, Why in my case is a little too complex. But what I want is more or less similar to wanting that both `make clean all` and `make all clean` be equivalent to `make clean && make all`.  I don't want the `clean` to be done after `all`, I don't want `clean` and `all` be interleaved, I don't want a standalone `make all` to start by doing a `clean`.

Comment: @AProgammer: then write a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, how about this hack (for a hack it undoubtedly is :-)).

Basically, you could run `make -d -n` plus your command arguments. The output will contain several lines like `Must remake target 'clean'`. This information tells you whether this run of *make* will attempt to build both `foo` *and* `bar`. If this turns out to be the case, just add a rule to cause the serialisation you want.

A sketch:

```
this := $(lastword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

ifndef DONTRECURSE
  targets-that-will-get-remade := $(patsubst %',%,$(shell ${MAKE} -f ${this} ${MAKECMDGOALS} --debug=b -n DONTRECURSE=nosiree | grep -Po "Must remake target '\K.*'"))
endif

ifeq (bar foo,$(sort $(filter bar foo,${targets-that-will-get-remade})))
foo: bar
endif

.PHONY: foo bar
foo bar:
    sleep 3
    : $@
```

So, you run *make*. `DONTRECURSE` is not set so the `$(shell …)` runs. That runs *make* a second time with the same makefile and goals, but adds the `-d` (debug) and `-n` (don't actually run the recipes) flags. `DONTRECURSE` is set to prevent a third copy of *make* running.

The expansion of all that is a list of the targets this run of make will attempt to build on this run. (Extracting the target names is pretty tiresome—there is probably a cleaner way.)

If this list of targets includes both `foo` and `bar`, simply add a `foo: bar` dependency. Job done. The `sleep 3` lines show this serialisation working when you use `-j4` (say).